# Alternating between two methods in ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, runnable

I would like to execute firstly one method and then another one, which depends on results of the first one. To keep it updated, I used ScheduledExecutorService:

```
Runnable alternatingExecution = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NetworkCall().execute(""); //this should be executed in first place
                methodTwo();                   //this should be executed after  
            }
        };

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(alternatingExecution, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

I tried to set `sleep();`in between, but unfortunately it won't work. As far as I know `Runnable` defines also only one method. So how could I resolve this issue to alternate between two methods constantly?

Comment: What is wrong with the existing one?

Comment: So, this doesn't work?

Comment: No, if execute only one method the `ScheduledExecutorService
` works, but since there are two methods, it won't.

Comment: @Unnamed I don't think that's what's happening. Do you get any error or just don't get the results you'd expect?

Comment: As it is the two methods will run inside run() sequentially. If methodTwo depends on the result of the first method you would use an IF. But I guess this is not what you are asking for.

Comment: @NiVeR I don't get any exception, but the second method just never executes. Although both methods work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Unnamed Try to check if the second method doesn't execute, or at least finish, as first. I think that's what happens.